# What do the sqaure brackets do in :not([])? - ':not([align])'

Tags: css

I'm new to the :not property in CSS.

When reading about it online, I understand that :not(x) attributes all other elements except for element 'x'. (as explained [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp)).

I'm adding to an existing codebase. This is in the css file:

```
table th:not([align]) {
    text-align: left; }
```

So what does this do? I don't understand it. Unless I add !important, it overrides this css:

```
.td-right {
    text-align: right;
}
```

But I would like to understand it properly and not have to use !important.

Comment: `table th:not([align])` selects all table' th elements which doesn't have an `align` attribute. In other words, the CSS is not applied to an element like `<th align="right">`.

Comment: It is also possible that `.td-right` was defined before the previous statement, that's why you must use `!important` to skip overwriting it

Comment: @MihaiMatei - No. `table th:not([align])` specificity is higher. (0,1,2) vs (0,1,0)

Comment: I tried it @Alohci and it works like he said. I don't have to use !important if I add align="right". Curious how you calculated those specificity values.